# How to make long html text expandable (preview)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I don't know what is the proper name of this component but I have a long HTML code (including images / videos /etc) and I'd like to show the `preview` of it in such a way that max 300px of it's height is chosen and below these 300px there is an expand button which shows entire code. How can I do that or what is the name of this component so that I could google it and inspire?

Comment: The names are expandable and collapsible